# init setting error: restore-uuid is wrong

Tags: initramfs, init

I upgraded my system via command line, apt gave me the error message:

init setting RESTORE-UUID=(uid)  is wrong drive doesn't exist. init will try to restore from /sda3

the system boots fine and the swap partition mounts.

where can I find this setting so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is located at `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo blkid | grep -i swap # note the UUID of the swap partition

sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume # edit the file
```

RESUME=UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b

```
* edit with correct UUID of swap partition from blkid command

sudo update-initramfs -u # update the /boot/initrd.img file
```